# Error with timer mm:ss

Tags: objective-c

I'm new to objective C.

i've been playing around with a countdown for some time now and i cant seem to make it work.

i've connecting very thing in storyboard and the buttons react, but it seems like its just randomly counting down.

why i isnt it counting down like 10:00 to 09:59.

```
- (void)showActivity{
    int currentTime = [time.text intValue];
    int newTime = currentTime - 1;
    int seconds = newTime % 60;
    int minutes = (newTime / 60) % 60;

    time.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02d:%02d", minutes, seconds];

}
```

Comment: How do you do `[time.text intValue]` with the format you're using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `time.text` is "10:00", then calling `[time.text intValue]` is just going to return the integer `10`.

I'd recommend creating a separate variable (perhaps an `NSTimeInterval`) that keeps track of how many seconds are left, and then make the `time` text label just responsible for displaying that as minutes:seconds.

e.g.

```
@property NSTimeInterval time; 
@property UILabel *timeLabel; // "time" in your original code

- (void)showActivity {
    NSTimeInterval newTime = self.time - 1;

    int minutes = floor(newTime / 60);
    int seconds = round(newTime - (minutes * 60));

    self.timeLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02d:%02d", minutes, seconds];
    self.time = newTime;
}
```